# Smoothest zero-centered periodic function $f$ with $f(0) > 0$

Tags: calculus, functions, periodic-functions

I am looking at periodic functions $f$ on $[0,2\pi]$ satisfying these constraints:

- $f(0) = 1$.
- $f$ is zero-centered, i.e. its integral from 0 to $2\pi$ is 0.
- $f$ is even. (More specifically, it's positive definite.)
- $f$ has a continuous first derivative.

I suspect that there is some sense in which cosine is the the smoothest function satisfying these constraints, but I'm not sure how to appropriately define "smooth" here nor how to prove that cosine is the smoothest such function. Is there a known result along these lines?

Comment: It probably has to do with the L2-norm (or Lp) of the function, the derivative, the second derivative, etc.

Comment: Your assumptions are very general and nowhere near uniquely describing the cosine function.

Comment: OK, looking around a bit I find that for splines the mean-square of the second derivative is used as a measure of smoothness.

Comment: If you want to minimize $\int_0^{2\pi} \ddot{f}^2 dx$ subject to the other constraints,  you can find a differential equation for $f$ using the [Euler-Lagrange equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Lagrange_equation). I would try but I don't have time now. Things to note: 1. Use the generalized version that takes higher-order derivatives in the Lagrangian. 2. You have to add Lagrange multipliers to enforce your first two constraints. 3. I suspect you won't actually get a cosine as a solution, since you will have a term that involves the 4th derivative of $f$; but it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I use $S\triangleq\int_0^{2\pi}f''(t)^2dt$ as my measure of smoothness (smaller number means smoother function), I've verified that cosine isn't the smoothest function. If $f$ has a continuous first derivative then it is square integrable over $[0,2\pi]$, and hence its Fourier series converges. I then find that

$$S = 8\pi\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^4 a_k^2$$

where $f(t)=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cos(k t)$ is the Fourier series for $f$. Subject to the condition that $f(0)=1$, i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = 1/2$, I find that $S$ is minimized when $a_k\propto 1/k^4$ for all $k$.

Comment: Maybe if you add a requirement that the image of $f$ is $[-1; 1]$, it will result in something more favorable? If we scale this here function to $[-1; 1]$ linearly, $S$ now becomes larger ($\approx 3.3$) than that for cosine. Also even scaled, $f(\frac\pi 2) = -\frac18\ne 0$—maybe one would want $f(\frac\pi 2) = 0$, requiring something like $f(t + \pi) = -(f)$?

Comment: FTR found your question after reading someone say “sines are chosen for harmonics because they are the smoothest periodic functions”. The usual motivation is that complex exponents are eigenfunctions of $d/dt$ and solving diff eqs was and is a big deal, so Fourier transform and the trigonometric basis got famous. But the argument about smoothness seems romantic; surely there is something which is at least in part true?

Comment: Wrote this because I’m a poor analyst, so if you get re-interested in this topic and find something, it will be great!

Comment: I found something similar to what you suggest. Among all zero-centered periodic functions with period $s > 0$ with $s^{-1}||f||_2^2 = \sigma^2$, whose Fourier series converges, the measure of smoothness $S(f)$ is minimized by a sinusoid of period $s$.